# Django: Add another field to django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am pretty new to django and I am very lost with django-registration. At the moment I have the django-registration set up an going but I need to add another field to it for a phone number. I need the phone number field in the registration field instead so I can use the api from twilio to send a verification link through text instead of email. How would I go about adding this one field to django-registration?

Comment: Can you show what you already have?

Comment: it is the default django-registration http://pastebin.com/dbTqd25d those are my forms and models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with django at work and for that kind of issue we used to attach a model to the user, example:

- You create a new model, for example profile with a OneToOneField to user
- Add your desired fields to that profile model, such as (tlf, country, language,log...)
- Create admin.py to manage this model (profile) at the same time you manage users in django admin

---

**Profile Model Example**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='phone')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='descripction')
    ...
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user']
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
```

---

**admin.py example**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals    
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    filter_horizontal = ['filter fields']  # example: ['tlf', 'country',...]
    verbose_name_plural = 'profiles'
    fk_name = 'user'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')

admin.site.unregister(User)  # Unregister user to add new inline ProfileInline
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)  # Register User with this inline profile
```

---

**Create an user and attach a profile to him**

```
# Create user
username = 'TestUser'
email = 'test@example.com'
passw = '1234'  
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, passw)

# Create profile
phone = '654654654'
desc = 'Test user profile'
new_profile = Profile(user=new_user, phone = phone, description=desc)
new_profile.profile_role = new_u_prole
new_profile.user = new_user

# Save profile and user
new_profile.save()
new_user.save()
```

---

Now you'll have this Profile model attached to each user, and you could add the fields you wish to Profile Model, and for example if you make:

`user = User.objects.get(id=1)`

you can access to his profile doing:

`user.profile`

and to access phone

`user.profile.phone`

Answer (score 1):

Not django-registration, but I customized django-userena once to add a custom field to the signup form.

You can view the code [here](https://github.com/brdhunga/entrepreneur-venture-django/blob/master/pitch/accounts/forms.py).

I am sure the process works more or less the same in django-registration too: overriding the signup form and adding custom fields.

However, django-registration is no longer maintained, I believe. It is a classic and works so well, but there are other options too.